# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'array' with Pandas and Bigquery

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I want to fetch some Bigquery data to a pandas dataframe.

My code is really simple:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=GCP_PROJECT_NAME)
sql_query = """
select ...
"""

job = self.bq_client.query(sql_query).result()
df = job.to_dataframe()
```

But I have an error on the last line (df = job.to_dataframe()):

```
df = job.to_dataframe()
venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py:244: UserWarning: Unable to determine type for field 'customer_email'.
  warnings.warn("Unable to determine type for field '{}'.".format(bq_field.name))
*** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'array'
```

Any ideas what can be the issue ?

Comment: At some point, a variable is set to `None` instead of some other, expected type. You should ask yourself why this is `None`, not why `None` doesn't have an `array` attribute. For a start, create a [mcve] and pay attention to error handling. Also, step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: The error code that you are receiving (pandas_helpers.py:244: UserWarning: Unable to determine type for field 'customer_email') basically tells you that in line 244 from your code “customer_email” there is no type assigned to it. This basically means that the field is returning or is being set to the NoneType. My best recommendation for your case is that you debug your code and try to find where this variable is being set to None.